# Local variable become null (Android)

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

from my android application I got a strange error message: NullPointerException (in last line code).

```
public static Integer getDefaultCalendarId(Context context) {
    String calendarInSettings = PrefsHelper.getDefaultCalendar(context);
    Calendar calendar = PrefsHelper.getCalendarFromPrefKey(context, calendarInSettings);
    if (calendar == null || !calendar.canEventEdit()) {
        return calculateDefaultCalendar(context);
    }
    boolean isChecked = false;
    for (Calendar checkedCalendar : PrefsHelper.getCheckedCalendars(context)) {
        if (checkedCalendar.getId() == calendar.getId()) {
            isChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    (1114 line) return isChecked ? calendar.getId() : calculateDefaultCalendar(context); // NullPointerException
}
```

Exception occurred on Samsung GT-N7000.

How could this happen?

**Update:**

calculateDefaultCalendar can return null, but getDefaultCalendarId return value - Integer (nullable)!

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.trial/xxx.view.EventEditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:986)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at xxx.EventHelper.java.lang.Integer getDefaultCalendarId(android.content.Context)(SourceFile:1114)
at xxx.view.EventEditActivity.void onCreate(android.os.Bundle)(SourceFile:306)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at xxx.EventHelper.java.lang.Integer getDefaultCalendarId(android.content.Context)(SourceFile:1114)
at xxx.view.EventEditActivity.void onCreate(android.os.Bundle)(SourceFile:306)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:986)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**update 2**

calculateDefaultCalendar:

```
private static Integer calculateDefaultCalendar(final Context context) {
    String account = PrefsHelper.getAccountName(context);
    if (account != null) {
        for (Calendar calendar : PrefsHelper.getCheckedCalendars(context)) {
            if (calendar.getOwnerAccount().equals(account) && calendar.canEventEdit()) {
                return calendar.getId();
            }
        }
    }

    for (Calendar calendar : PrefsHelper.getCheckedCalendars(context)) {
        if (calendar.canEventEdit()) {
            return calendar.getId();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

***Update 3***

The error repeats regularly on:

product / android version

LT26i_1257-3921 / 4.0.4

MK16i_1249-8137 / 4.0.4

SCH-I500 / 2.3.5

SCH-I500 / 4.0.4

Comment: Definitely need more code.  But I can tell you NPEs are pretty easy to figure out.

Comment: on what line did u get NPE ??

Comment: it would help if you provide the stack trace

Comment: Wouldn't a debugger tell you where the null is? My guess is the context you are passing into the method is null

Comment: post `calculateDefaultCalendar()` method code

Comment: Why don't you put a breakpoint on that line and inspect each value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return isChecked ? calendar.getId() : calculateDefaultCalendar(context);
```

I suspect `calendar.getId()` returns `int` not `Integer`. This would mean that `calculateDefaultCalendar(context)`, which returns an `Integer`, first needs to be auto-unboxed to `int` and the resulting `int` has to be auto-boxed to an `Integer`. If `isChecked` is false and `calculateDefaultCalendar(context)` returns `null` then this will result in `NPE`. See the following simplified equivalent code, for example:

```
class N2 {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println(check()); 
  }
  static Integer check()
  {
    return false ? 0 : fNull(); 
  }
  static Integer fNull() 
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

A search for relevant terms `auto-boxing`, `NullPointerException` and `ternary` brings up many similar hots.

Answer (score 1):

If `calender.getId()` returns an `int`, you are running into issues with auto-boxing.  Since the most likely culprit is the return value of `calculateDefaultCalendar()`, most likely the compiler is trying to auto-unbox the `null` return value. To fix this, you can simply manually box the return value of `calender.getId()` with `Integer.valueOf(calendar.getId())`. This will ensure that the returned value is boxed as an `Integer` and then the return value of `calculateDefaultCalendar()` won't be auto-unboxed.

Answer (score 0):

Stating the obvious, one of these is null:

- <s>`calendar`</s> (eliminated, called successfully previously in code)
- <s>The return from `getId()`</s> (eliminated, called successfully previously in code)
- The return from `calculateDefaultCalendar`
- <s>`context`</s> (eliminated, called successfully previously in code)

Looks like `calculateDefaultCalendar` is returning null for some reason.  We'll need the code for that before we can help any more.

---

OK, now that we have `calculateDefaultCalendar`, we can keep eliminating.  From your comment, it looks like the problem is that these two conditional statements

```
if (calendar.getOwnerAccount().equals(account) && calendar.canEventEdit()) {
    return calendar.getId();
}
```

and

```
if (calendar.canEventEdit()) {
    return calendar.getId();
}
```

are not evaluating to `true` (otherwise they would return an integer, you say).  So, the next thing to do is make sure that

- `account` is not null
- `canEventEdit()` is true

Usually, NPE tracing is like this, it's pretty easy.  Just work backwards through the code until something puts out `NULL`, and that's the source.

Comment: i dont think it'd throw NPE if calendar is null, he's already checking it in his if.

Comment: Yeah you're right, thanks.  Actually looks like that narrows it down quite neatly.

Comment: But stacktrace points out line 1114 (return in getDefaultCalendarId), not on conditions.